# Xerox Phaser 3100MFP not working

Tags: drivers, printing, xerox

I have installed the latest version of Ubuntu on my system. My problem is that
I am not able to find and install the proper drivers for my printer/scanner combination; the [Xerox Phaser 3100MFP](http://www.office.xerox.com/multifunction-printer/multifunction-under-30ppm/phaser-3100mfp/spec-enus.html).

Although it *is* recognised by the system and my print jobs appear as completed, in fact they are not printed at all.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

The link by Orestis is really great one.

In short the reason of your problems can be 64-bit. Xerox drivers for Phaser 3100MFP are 32-bit and that's why you'll have to install some 32-bit libraries.

First of all, download the driver from Xerox official site. It will have a setup file for installing driver in Ubuntu's database. Unpack and install it. It may need to run with sudo like this:

```
sudo ./setup
```

This action can have a problem cause it is needed to have libjpeg62:i386 installed. so run before it:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62:i386
```

So now if you'll search for drivers in Printers - it will find appropriate but it won't still work cause there are some 32-bit libraries that are missing. 
As for as i know, Ubuntu is using CUPS, so to find out which libraries are needed, run this:

```
readelf -d  /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoprinterbin
```

The output will be something like this:

```
Tag        Type                         Name/Value
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcupsimage.so.2]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcups.so.2]
```

So the libraries which have type 'needed' are needed to be installed. 
For example to resolve lipcupsimage.so.2 you need to install 'libcupsimage2:i386'
 (':i386' - means 32 bit system, don't forget to include it). The command will look like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libcupsimage:i386
```

After that it should work fine. I had the same problem with my printer Xerox Phaser 3100MFP - it resolved after i installed only 'libcupsimage'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following guide, skipping over items not relevant for Ubuntu. Since I had it working before and my current Ubuntu setup is the product of two upgrades, there *may* have been a few less steps required in my case.

[Arch Wiki: Xerox Phaser 3100MFP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xerox_Phaser_3100MFP)

By the way, if you're running 64-bit Ubuntu, you may need to install the package `libjpeg62:i386`.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please include at least the essential parts of your solution to the answer as the source in the link may change or become unavailable in the future.